# How to format number in input in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, input

I am using angularjs and I have an input like

```
<input type='text' pattern="[0-9.,]+" ng-model="treasuryValue"  />
```

I set first value to input using ng-model tag. But while setting first value to input my pattern doesn't work. Pattern tag runs first time when input changes. How can I format value in input while setting it's first value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-pattern` attribute,

```
<input type='text' ng-pattern="/[0-9.,]+/" ng-model="treasuryValue" />
```

To format the value initially,

```
function formCtrl($scope,$filter){
    $scope.treasuryValue = '33,345';
    $scope.$watch('treasuryValue', function() {
        $scope.name = $filter('number')($scope.name);
  });
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/4640/)**

Comment: nothing changed. there is no difference between ng-pattern and pattern tags in this case.

Comment: Works for me here **http://jsfiddle.net/KGd8K/1049/**. Im setting a string value which does not work, but if you change it to int/float it will work **http://jsfiddle.net/KGd8K/1050/**.

Comment: Doesn't work. I entered 324234. I expect 324,234. But it returns 324234

Comment: The pattern won't do this for you initially. You need to you use filters for that.

Comment: How can I add a filter to ng-model. I think filters can be able to in expression which includes paranthesis as {{}}

Comment: You need to add filter in controller. Check this **http://jsfiddle.net/KGd8K/1051/**

Comment: you already entered number with commas like 33,345. but my data is 33345. I want to that when I set 33345 to input initally, input must show it like 33,345.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77708/discussion-between-neverwinter-and-shaunak-d).

Comment: Yeah that's it. This (jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/4640) is what I want. Thank you! @Shaunak D